# Is there a way to batch process Outlook contacts via category?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

I would like to select the contacts in a category and switch them to another category.
Can this be automated?

Comment: Do you mean automated as in without human intervention or as in manually batch multiple at the same time? Your title and question are somewhat in conflict ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing the following:

1. Open your Contacts folder
2. `View` -> `Current View` -> `By Category`
3. The Contacts will be grouped by Category
4. Right click on the Category header row you wish to change
5. Select `Categories...`
6. Change as necessary
7. Click `OK`

Done!

Screenshots below from Outlook 2003, process is same for all versions I think:

[image: Contacts by Category]

[image: Contact Categories]

Comment: Extra info: Outlook 2010 (beta) does not seem to support right-clicking the category group, you need to expand it out and shift-select all the items.
Right click > categorize > all categories then gives you a list box where you can tick and untick multiple categories.

Comment: GREAT! This works. +1 and accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you switch to list view and use grouping on the Categories column, you should be able to drag and drop contacts between Catgetegories groups.

Comment: Only works if there are already contacts in the category (or categories) that you want to move to. Unused categories will not be shown in the list view. See my answer for how to access unused categories.

Answer (score 2):

It is almost certainly possible if you are willing to write some code.  This is ne of the best resources for scripting Outlook. http://www.outlookcode.com/

Comment: Thanks, +1, but I'm not able to write anything.